# Orchard cms in mvc 3 application how to remove unwanted url content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor, orchardcms

Orchard CMS in MVC3 Application.

How to remove the unwanted "url" content?

Example: http://www.xxxxxx.com/**HotelsOnly/HotelList**/Region?region=2114&total=848

```
 In routes {area,” HotelsOnly”} ,{controller,”HotelList”}
```

Url How to change or remove this(/HotelsOnly/HotelList)

Example: http://www.xxxxxx.com**/Region**?region=2114&total=848

Explain how to remove? Please show any Example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you use this type of rout url it's blow

```
routes.MapRoute(
              "Regis", // Route nameRegister
              "Test/Artical/Show/{id}", // URL with parameters
              new { controller = "Artical", action = "Show", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

in my project i use rout like this it's below

```
@Html.RouteLink("click", "Regis", 1);
```

1 i set a default value for example . so my url look like this

```
http://localhost:xxxx/Test/Artical/Show/1
```

I remove Test from my url like this it's below

you will change your rout like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
              "Regis", // Route nameRegister
              "Test/Artical/Show/{id}", // URL with parameters
              new { controller = "Artical", action = "Show", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
          );
```

and after change rout then my url look like  this

```
http://localhost:xxxx/Artical/Show/1
```

i think this will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
new RouteDescriptor {
    Route = new Route(
        "Region",
        new RouteValueDictionary {
            {"area", "HotelsOnly"},
            {"controller", "HotelList"},
            {"action", "Index"}
        },
        new RouteValueDictionary(),
        new RouteValueDictionary {
            {"area", "HotelsOnly"}
        },
        new MvcRouteHandler())
},
```